# Using FFmpeg to concatenate multiple videos with trimmed start and end and with different fps, resolutions, audio codecs

Tags: unity-game-engine, ffmpeg

I'd like to use FFmpeg in a Unity project to concatenate multiple videos, selected or recorded by the user. The Unity plugin is providing FFmpeg 3.4.1 and it's possible to call all the normal oneline commands. But I'm not sure about piping outputs to next commands.

I managed it to concatenate videos from a list.txt in general but I have some issues with their target framerate and async audio streams.

This is what I do right now:

`ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt output.mp4 -hide_banner`

In my list.txt there are two mp4 files with inpoint and outpoint data:

```
file video_01.mp4
inpoint 5
outpoint 20.2800006866455
file video_02.mp4
inpoint 10
outpoint 24.1599998474121
```

Those two videos have 50 and 25 fps, one is without audio (or muted) the other one has audio.

What is the best way to have a robust output from different sources with a defined video resolution, fps, codec and audio stream? Do I have to use -filter-complex?

Comment: Will this concatenated video be shown to the user only?

Comment: To concatenate arbitrary inputs you need to make sure they all have the same parameters and the same number and type of streams. You can do this by using various filters, and then they can be concatenated with the concat filter. This can all be done in one command. See the examples of using the concat filter in the duplicate links.